# Is it possible to make a Windows installation that "resets" at every boot?

Tags: windows

I want to make a completely secure pc where any changes or installs will get reverted at every boot, so only pre installed software and files is on the pc on every boot? I was thinking something like a bootable windows installation on a usb drive that only save changes to ram or something like that? Is it possible, and how could it be achieved?

Comment: Software & learning material requests are both off-topic here, but see [Deep Freeze](https://www.faronics.com/en-uk/home) for the industry standard solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was in my school they used a software called [Deep Freeze](https://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze) which produced the desired results as you want.